# If more than 1 show this

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm a JS beginner and I would like to make, that if on list is more than 1 marker, show text1 else show text2

Here is basic code

```
function makeSidebar() {
    var html = "";

    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
        html += '<div class="pin-details col-xs-3" onClick="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" ><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="map/pin_grey.png"/></div><div class="col-xs-10"><span>'+gmarkers[i].myname+'</span><p>ul. '+gmarkers[i].myaddress+'<br>'+gmarkers[i].myaddresstwo+'</div></div>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
  }
```

and I'm trying to make like this

```
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      var markersVisible = gmarkers[i].getVisible();
      if (markersVisible.length == 1) {
        if (markersVisible) {
        html += '<div class="pin-details col-xs-3" onClick="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" ><div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img1" alt="Map Pin" src="map/pin_grey.png"/></div><div class="col-xs-10"><span>'+gmarkers[i].myname+'</span><p>ul. '+gmarkers[i].myaddress+'<br>'+gmarkers[i].myaddresstwo+'</div></div>';
       }
     }
      else{
        if (markersVisible){
         html += '<div class="pin-details col-xs-3" onClick="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" ><div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img1" alt="Map Pin" src="map/marker_red.png"/></div><div class="col-xs-10"><span>'+gmarkers[i].myname+'</span><p>ul. '+gmarkers[i].myaddress+'<br>'+gmarkers[i].myaddresstwo+'</div></div>';
              }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write your question , so i did not understand your problem but here is some changes , less lines

```
for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) 
{
    var markersVisible = gmarkers[i].getVisible();
    if (markersVisible) 
        html += '<div class="pin-details col-xs-3" onClick="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" ><div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img1" alt="Map Pin" src="map/'+(markersVisible.length == 1 ? "pin_grey" : "marker_red")+'.png"/></div><div class="col-xs-10"><span>'+gmarkers[i].myname+'</span><p>ul. '+gmarkers[i].myaddress+'<br>'+gmarkers[i].myaddresstwo+'</div></div>';"col-xs-10"><span>'+gmarkers[i].myname+'</span><p>ul. '+gmarkers[i].myaddress+'<br>'+gmarkers[i].myaddresstwo+'</div></div>';

}
```

Comment: How to show another "html" if there is only 1 marker on list and another "html" is more than 1 marker

Comment: here is it     (markersVisible.length == 1 ? "pin_grey" : "marker_red")

if markersVisible.length equal 1 it will set the picture to pin_grey else it will set the picture to marker.

can you provide the HTML code

Comment: Maybe i write my post bad.  2nd code it's what I wrote to get what i want but its not working

Comment: add your html code to your post , i will find a solution

Comment: html its not necessary its only <div id="side_bra"></div> method its only in this function